# Rails named scope for left joined model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table named `acts`, and I'll like to run a query that rolls up act values for a whole week. I'd like to make sure the query always returns one row for each day of the week, even if there are no records for that day. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
  def self.this_week_totals
    sunday = Time.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    connection.select_values(<<-EOQ)
        SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(end_time - start_time), '0:00:00') AS total_time
        FROM    generate_series(0, 6) AS s(t)
        LEFT JOIN acts
        ON      acts.day = '#{sunday}'::date + s.t
        WHERE   deleted_at IS NULL
        GROUP BY s.t
        ORDER BY s.t
    EOQ
  end
```

Is there any way I could make this a named scope on the Act class so it can be combined with other conditions, for example to filter the Acts by a `client_id`? Since `acts` isn't in my `FROM`, but is part of the `LEFT JOIN`, I'm guessing not, but perhaps someone out there knows a way.

Edit: Just to clarify, the goal is for this method to *always* return exactly 7 Act objects, regardless of what's in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want your query object to be chainable it must be an ActiveRelation object

`where`, `select`, `order` and the other Arel objects return ActiveRelation objects that are chainable, so if the below works you can chain off of the returned query object

note in rails 3 and up having a class method that returns an ActiveRelation is basically the same as a scope, they are both chainable query objects

```
class Act
  def self.this_week_totals
    sunday = Time.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    select("COALESCE(SUM(end_time - start_time), '0:00:00') AS total_time")
      .from("generate_series(0, 6) AS s(t)")
      .joins("LEFT JOIN acts ON acts.day = '#{sunday}'::date + s.t")
      .where("deleted_at IS NULL")
      .group("s.t")
      .order("s.t")
  end
  # ...
end

client_id = params[:client_id]
Act.this_week_totals.where("client_id = ?", client_id)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from

Comment: Actually if you make that a RIGHT JOIN, it works! I've always ignored RIGHT JOINs since they are trivial to re-write as LEFT JOINs, but here is a case where I need one. If you edit your answer I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: Hmm, one caveat with this approach is that if I add another join, say to the `clients` table, rows will start disappearing. This is because I'm joining `clients` where `clients.id = acts.client_id`, and the RIGHT JOIN makes `client_id` NULL, so the comparison is false. This isn't an issue when the primary table is `generate_series` and I'm LEFT JOINing to a subquery that combines `acts` and `clients`. I'm not sure how to INNER JOIN to clients while RIGHT JOINing to generate_series, and still always get 7 rows.

Comment: updated answer to use `from` - if from method does what I think it should then this will make it act exactly as your original query - I have never used from method, one of the rare cases where it should come in handy?

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `from`. That does let me use LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT, but alas joining other tables is still broken: I can't do `FROM generate_series INNER JOIN clients LEFT JOIN acts`, because `clients` needs to join with `acts`, not `generate_series`. Instead I need a subquery joining `acts`+`clients`, then put that into the LEFT JOIN clause. Even so, this has to be the most satisfying SO question I've asked: I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Although I really thought I could use the solution from @house9, I don't see any way to avoid compromising on at least one of these goals:

1. Always yield 7 Act objects.
2. Return an ActiveRelation so I can compose this method with other scopes.
3. Permit joining to the `clients` table.

Here is the part-SQL/part-Ruby solution I'm actually using, which sadly gives up on point #2 above and also returns tuples rather than Acts:

```
def self.this_week(wk=0)
  sunday = Time.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
  sunday += wk.weeks
  not_deleted.where("day BETWEEN ? AND ?", sunday, sunday + 7.days)
end

scope :select_sum_total_hours,
  select("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM COALESCE(SUM(end_time - start_time), '0:00:00'))/3600 AS total_hours")

scope :select_sum_total_fees,
  joins(:client).
  select("SUM(COALESCE(clients.rate, 0) * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM COALESCE(end_time - start_time, '0:00:00'))/3600) AS total_fees")


def self.this_week_totals_by_day(wk=0)
  totals = Hash[
    this_week(wk)
      .select("EXTRACT(DAY FROM day) AS just_day")
      .select_sum_total_hours
      .select_sum_total_fees
      .group("day")
      .order("day")
      .map{|act| [act.just_day, [act.total_hours.to_f, act.total_fees.to_money]]}
  ]
  sunday = Time.now.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
  sunday += wk.weeks
  (0..6).map do |x|
    totals[(sunday + x.days).strftime("%d")] || [0, 0.to_money]
  end
end
```

That could be DRYed up a bit, and it would produce errors if there were ever a month with fewer than 7 days, but hopefully it shows what I'm doing. The scopes for `this_week`, `select_sum_total_hours`, and `select_sum_total_fees` are used elsewhere, so I want to pull them out into scopes rather than repeating them in several big raw SQL strings.